# How to access the name of a object in AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj

I need to compare the execution of generated program code blocks. I wrote some Pointcuts, one of them monitors every object initialization withing my namespace.

```
Student var1 = new Student();
```

While findind the type of the created object is fairly simple, i didn't find a way to determine the name of the created object.

```
pointcut ObjectInitialization(): 
   call(new(..)) &&(within(MYNAMESPACE));

before() : ObjectInitialization() {
   // how do I get "var1"?
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you cant really do this in the pointcut around `new`. its unrelated to assignment.

Comment: With AspectJ you can get member names, but not local variable names. Which of those two is your use case?